# JQuery mobile multi-page

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

When run the following code, firefox 17.0.5 gives an "error loading message", when I want to open the car page. But it works properly in IE8.

Then I found an example here 
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/multipage-template.html
I opened that website with firefox 17.0.5, works. Then I viewed the source code, almost the same structure as mine. But when I download the html and run it, neither IE8 nor FF works. What's wrong here? I m linked to jQuery moible from another project, know nothing about web development. Please help. :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <!-- Start of first page -->

    <div data-role="page" id="menu">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Menu</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <p>What vehicles do you like?</p>
            <p><a href="#one">Cars</a></p>
            <p><a href="#two">Trains</a></p>
            <p><a href="#three">Planes</a></p>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /header -->
    </div><!-- /page -->

    <!-- / Page 2 -->

    <div data-role="page" id="one">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Cars</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <p>Content about cars</p>
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Cars</h4>
        </div><!-- /header -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error on firebug console ?

Comment: @dreamweiver Hi, I googled how to use firebug, that's powerful tool thank you for the tip. However, I run the pasted html in FF, firebug->console->errors, it's empty.

Comment: :Here check this , i feel its working fine.http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/mhN4X/

Comment: @dreamweiver I opened the link you gave with FF, and that works fine. Did you change the code? (Still confused about the inconsistency)

Comment: i didnt change anything :) your code has been retained. i guess something was wrong in your html doc, may be some tag`s were miss spelt.

Comment: Anyway you can verify your code with the code on jsfiddle.

Comment: @dreamweiver Thank you for the support! I found the reason. The website example didn't work because of the ref address, I should change it into an absolute one. And then, I relocate my html into another folder without space, without changing any code, now it works on FF too. :D again, thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem too, And I found that the problem is using the protocol `file://`, You can’t work with `jquerymobile` with the protocol `file://` it has to be a web address. After moving my project to my local server, with protocol `http://` it worked immediately.

Source : http://doeswhat.com/2011/03/08/jquery-mobile-error-loading-page/

**EDIT:** 
In your case, avoiding spaces in URL address solves your problem

Comment: Thanks! it could be one reason. But the problem that I have met is because of the space! FF could not decode the space in address I think, IE8 decodes it as a %20. Now I tried it with another folder without any space, it works. "No space in address" might be a common sence for web developers, and I'll bare it in mind from now on too :D